# filling a a list and a dictionary with user input then fill the dictionay with a list and a variabe(changed)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Write a "CreationRang" function, which will take the dictionary of candidates (DC) as parameters, to calculate the FG of each candidate and save the result in a list of ranks to be returned. In the rank list we find the ranks of the candidates sorted in descending order according to the FG, such that each element corresponds to a candidate and is represented by a list: CIN, score (real), rank (integer) (in this order) FG=4*moyGen+2*mp1+2*mp2+1*ms1+1*ms2 i don't understand how am i supposed to make this work. help

Comment: can you provide some input and output you except?

Comment: for example moyGen,mp1,mp2,ms1,ms2 they are floats

Comment: maybe i can contact you on whatsapp or other platform so i can explain more the whole code

Answer (score 2):

your approach to append in the dictionary is wrong. `DF={key:value}` THis is wrong Instead of this use `DF[key] = value`.

```py
def RemplirDF(nf):
    DF={}
    
    for i in range(nf):
        L=[] # edited
        cf=input("donner le code filière :")
        lf=input("donner le libellé filière :")
        niu=input("donner le nom institution universitaire :")
        c=int(input("donner la capacité :"))
        L.append(lf)
        L.append(niu)
        L.append(c)
        DF[cf] = L #edited
    return DF
```

Comment: it does work and i'd like to get more help in other functions if it is possible

Comment: ok but where and how i tired but i couldn't post it it says it is closed check maybe you find it in my profile i just posted it, or just let me know how can i contact you

Comment: i can't talk there , it says 'You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"

Comment: i can't use the stackover flow chat what can i do

Comment: okay it is done but don't mind the oldq